# Upgrading to Ruby 1.9 on Mac OSX 10.4

Tags: ruby, macos

I have an older powerbook running 10.4. It has Ruby 1.8.2 on it but I want to upgrade to 1.9. Other people suggested using macports and I tried it but am getting some weird errors. Can anyone assist?

sudo port install ruby19 +nosuffix

--->  Computing dependencies for ruby19
--->  Configuring gperf
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_gperf/work/gperf-3.0.4" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --infodir=/opt/local/share/info " returned error 1
Command output: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
=== configuring in lib (/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_gperf/work/gperf-3.0.4/lib)
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure '--prefix=/opt/local'  '--infodir=/opt/local/share/info' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc-4.0
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
configure: error: ./configure failed for lib

Error: The following dependencies failed to build: libiconv gperf ncurses ncursesw openssl zlib readline
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
Before reporting a bug, first run the command again with the -d flag to get complete output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Xcode. I think the latest for 10.4 is Xcode 2.5. From http://www.macports.org/install.php :

> Please note that in order to install and run MacPorts on Mac OS X, your system must have installations of the following components:
>
> 1. Apple's Xcode Developer Tools (version 3.2.1 or later for Snow Leopard,
>       3.1.4 or later for
>       Leopard, or 2.5 for Tiger), found at the Apple Developer Connection
>       site or on your Mac OS X installation CDs/DVD. Ensure that the optional components for command line development are installed ("Unix Development" in the Xcode 3.x installer).
> 2. The X11 windowing environment (A.K.A. “X11 User”) for ports that depend on the functionality it provides to run.
>
> *The “X11 User” package is an optional installation on your system CDs/DVD for Tiger, enabled through the “Customize” button of the installer, whereas it is included by default on Leopard and Snow Leopard.
>
> *You can use the xorg-server port instead of Apple's X11.app if you wish.

Check your mac installation disc or download it from apple here (you'll need ADC membership which is free):

http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html